# Best way to pass data from a middleware to views in Django without modifying request object

Tags: python, django, django-middleware

I am new to Django and I want to send some information to my views function from the Middleware which I have created inside my Project. 
Is there any way of doing this specific task and if not How can we modify the  request object??

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please post more code to show what you had done, and what you want.

Comment: The `request` object is just a Python object. You can add whatever properties you like to it.

Comment: But I think it is immutable

Comment: @AbhishekSoam that's clearly false. The contrib.auth middleware for example adds the `user` attribute to the request; your code can do the same.

Comment: @ Daniel Roseman Would you please make me understand in term of example or code? That would be very helpful .

Comment: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py#L24